# Getting fractional portion of a decimal number from a BigDecimal input

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal

I am trying to use BigDecimal to separate the decimal number into two parts (whole part and fractional part).

```
BigDecimal price1  = BigDecimal.valueOf(300.50);
BigDecimal price2  = BigDecimal.valueOf(300.05);
BigDecimal fractionalPart1  = price1.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
BigDecimal fractionalPart2  = price2.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
System.out.println(fractionalPart1.movePointRight(price1.scale()).abs().intValue());  // Output is 5
System.out.println(fractionalPart2.movePointRight(price2.scale()).abs().intValue());  // Output is 5
```

The output in both the above cases is 5. How to correct this (leaving the option of converting it into String) so it gives 50 and 5 correctly.

Comment: how is "price" variable defined ?

Comment: updated the question with correct variables

Comment: If you want to reliably get the whole part, I'd try `price.setScale(0, ROUND_DOWN)`.  Then subtract the result from `price` to get the fraction.  Note that if the original number is negative, with this method the fraction will also be negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, here is the solution.

By using valueOf and specifying the double value, the trailing zero is dropped. And this affects the scale.  If you want to preserve the trailing zero, then you need to use the String constructor version of BigDecimal.

So change these

```java
      BigDecimal price1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(300.50);
      BigDecimal price2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(300.05);
```

To these

```java
      BigDecimal price1 = new BigDecimal("300.50");
      BigDecimal price2 = new BigDecimal("300.05");
```